# why is my RewriteRule not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to be able to Rewrite a following url:

```
www.mysite.com/en/contact
```

to something like this

```
www.mysite.com?l=en&p=contact
```

but keep the structure.

I tried the following RewriteRule:

```
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?l=$1&p=$2 [L]
```

but the browser then wants to load all the included scripts like the css from

```
 www.mysite.com/en
```

How can I tell the browser, that it shouldn't follow the url link?
Or something like that

Thank you for your help

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 methods to solve this:

1) Use base tag inside head tag

---

```
<base href='/'>
```

---

2)Use relative links

---

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/style.css'>
```

---

Here the browser looks for the CSS file in the folder in the root named CSS, whatever the URL request may be.

Comment: Yes of course!
Thank you for bringing it back to mind
Had used that a while back but just couldn't figure it out again
Thanx for that